# Show that W is a Linear Estimator.

Tags: statistics, regression, economics

Hello I need help doing a proof. I need to show that W is a linear estimator of the following equation don't now where to start.

```
              W = (1/8)Y' + (1/3)Y'' + (1/6)Y''' + (3/8)Y''''
```

Please help!
Thank you

Comment: What are $Y',Y'',Y''',Y''''$?  Is it helpful that $\frac18 +\frac13+\frac16+\frac38=1$?

Comment: Each Y is a different variable. Y' = Y prime, Y'' = Y 2 prime. Each Y is just a separate variable.